# Generating .rdlc report works on local but not after deploying to azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, report, rdlc

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application I have the following method:

```
public ActionResult SendMailAsAStudent(string studentId, string companyId, int applicationId, string companyCVR, string studentCPR)
        {
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var student = manager.FindById(studentId);
            var company = manager.FindById(companyId);
            var application = db.Applications.Find(applicationId);
            Project projectobj = db.Projects.Find(application.ProjectId);


            var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
            myMessage.From = new MailAddress("info@leepio.dk");
            myMessage.AddTo(student.Email);
            myMessage.AddTo(company.Email);
            myMessage.Subject ="The contract for " + projectobj.Title + " is signed!";
            myMessage.Html = "Here is the final contract";

            LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
            localReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Contracts/Contract.rdlc");

            ReportParameter cvrParameter = new ReportParameter("cvrParameter", companyCVR);
            ReportParameter companyNameParameter = new ReportParameter("companyNameParameter", company.CompanyName);
            ReportParameter companyAddressParameter = new ReportParameter("companyAddressParameter", company.Address);
            ReportParameter studentNameParameter = new ReportParameter("studentNameParameter", student.FirstName+" "+student.LastName);
            ReportParameter studentAddressParameter = new ReportParameter("studentAddressParameter", student.Address);
            ReportParameter studentZipCodeParameter = new ReportParameter("studentZipCodeParameter", student.ZipCode);
            ReportParameter jobStartDateParameter = new ReportParameter("jobStartDateParameter", projectobj.StartDate);
            ReportParameter jobEndDateParameter = new ReportParameter("jobEndDateParameter", projectobj.EndDate);
            ReportParameter jobDescriptionParameter = new ReportParameter("jobDescriptionParameter", projectobj.Description);
            ReportParameter jobHoursPerWeekParameter = new ReportParameter("jobHoursPerWeekParameter", projectobj.HoursPerWeek.ToString());
            ReportParameter jobHourlyRateParameter = new ReportParameter("jobHourlyRateParameter", projectobj.HourlyRate.ToString());
            ReportParameter cprParameter = new ReportParameter("cprParameter", studentCPR);

            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { cprParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { cvrParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { companyNameParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { companyAddressParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { studentNameParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { studentAddressParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { studentZipCodeParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { jobStartDateParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { jobEndDateParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { jobDescriptionParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { jobHoursPerWeekParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { jobHourlyRateParameter });

            string reportType = "PDF";
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string fileNameExtension = "pdf";
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;
            var renderedBytes = localReport.Render(reportType, "", out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attatchment; filename=Contract." + fileNameExtension);

           MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(renderedBytes);

           myMessage.AddAttachment(stream, "Contract.pdf");


            var apiKey = "key removed for this post";
            var transportWeb = new Web(apiKey);
            transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);

            Contract contract = new Contract();
            contract.StudentId = studentId;
            contract.CompanyId = companyId;
            contract.CVR = companyCVR;
            contract.ApplicationId = applicationId;
            contract.IsSigned = true;

            db.Contracts.Add(contract);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Projects");
        }
```

If I run it on the localhost it works, sends the mail with the report file succesfully. When deploying to Azure it no longer works. Commenting out the report generation and adding it as an attachment makes it work, so I pinpointed the problem to be around the report generation.

What can possibly cause it to no longer work on the site? I have checked the parameters to be not null.

Comment: You need to be more specific than "doesn't work". Any exceptions thrown? My initial suspicion is that  your azure instance does not have the report runtime installed.

Comment: No exceptions or anything like that, tried to find out the problem with F12 but nothing. It might be the case like you described, however I have Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms in my references. Are they not installed when I click Publish?

Comment: also both CopyLocal are set to TRUE

Comment: There must be an exception, do you know how to remote debug on Azure?

Comment: After a quick google I found out how to do it. Another question I have is does selecting "Release" other than "Debug" in Visual Studio change the results? EDIT: still works on my local machine even with "Release" selected

Comment: If you want to remote debug you should deploy in debug mode but if that is a production site I would recommend setting up a QA environment in Azure.

Comment: Well it is a small site so I don't have a separate testing server right now. Trying to figure out this report generating issue. Is remote debugging my best bet in fixing it?

Comment: I am stuck with the first thing here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252075(v=vs.140).aspx . Add the ReportViewer control from the Reporting section of the Toolbox to the form or Web page in your project. I cannot find it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116387/discussion-between-crowcoder-and-crystyxn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned on the error showing in the web.config like so:

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
```

Then I got the error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Thanks to Crowcoder I finally found out the problem, I had to install Microsoft.Report.Viewer 10.0.0 from the NuGet package manager!

Built, published and now it works!